# jqmobile 1.4 panel with FooterBar

Tags: javascript

I use following Code to open an Panel in FooterBar. After 5 times open the panel
nothing happens. FooterBar is not be clickabel. Panel cant be close anymore.

What can I do?

Please advise, Thanks

JavaScript

```
$("#FooterBar_Stundenerfassung_0").on("click", function () {
    // text you get from Ajax
    var content = "<h2>Hilfe</h2><ul><li>Probieren geht &uuml;ber Studieren</li><li>Liebe geht &uuml;ber Triebe</li><li>Tante f&auml;llt &uuml;ber Kante</li></ul>";

    // close button
    var closeBtn = $('<a href="#" data-rel="close" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-btn-a ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-left">zurück</a>');

    // Popup body - set width is optional - append button and Ajax msg
    var popup = $("<div/>", {
        "data-role": "panel"

    }).append(content).append(closeBtn);

    // Append it to active page
    $.mobile.pageContainer.append(popup);

    // Create it and add listener to delete it once it's closed
    // open it
    $("[data-role=panel]").panel({
        position: "left",
        theme: "a",
        display: "overlay",
        animate: true,
        dismissible: "false",
        swipeClose: "false",
        beforeposition: function () {
            $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("getActivePage")

        },
        afterclose: function () {
            $(this).remove();

        },
        afteropen: function () {
            /* do something */
        }

    }).panel("open");
});
```

End JavaScript

Comment: It would be good if you posted at least part of your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML is includet at the var content and var closeBtn. I have no HTML with Div

I have this sample from a PopUp Example, and there works well.

brgds Ramon